# Elasticsearch search mac address ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I'm a new in ror and elasticsearch.

I have my model.

```
class Ddhcpconf < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Tire::Model::Search
    include Tire::Model::Callbacks


    tire.mapping do
        indexes :mac, :index_analyser => 'keyword', :search_analyser => 'keyword'
        indexes :ip, :index_analyser => 'keyword', :search_analyser => 'keyword'
    end 

    def self.search(params)
        tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 15) do |s|
            s.query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND"} if    params[:query].present?
            s.sort { by :ip, "asc" } if params[:query].blank?
        end
    end
end
```

And I want to search a mac address I get this error :

```
400 : {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[ekOgLtQNSSCtW0MgoPA6wQ][ddhcpconfs][2]: SearchParseException[[ddhcpconfs][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"00:14:22:47:41:9f\",\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},\"size\":15}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[ddhcpconfs] Failed to parse query [00:14:22:47:41:9f]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse '00:14:22:47:41:9f': Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 5.\nWas expecting one of:\n <EOF> \n <AND> ...\n <OR> ...\n <NOT> ...\n \"+\" ...\n \"-\" ...\n <BAREOPER> ...\n \"(\" ...\n \"*\" ...\n \"^\" ...\n <QUOTED> ...\n <TERM> ...\n <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\n <PREFIXTERM> ...\n <WILDTERM> ...\n <REGEXPTERM> ...\n \"[\" ...\n \"{\" ...\n <NUMBER> ...\n ]; nested: ParseException[Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 5.\nWas expecting one of:\n <EOF> \n <AND> ...\n <OR> ...\n <NOT> ...\n \"+\" ...\n \"-\" ...\n <BAREOPER> ...\n \"(\" ...\n \"*\" ...\n \"^\" ...\n <QUOTED> ...\n <TERM> ...\n <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\n <PREFIXTERM> ...\n <WILDTERM> ...\n <REGEXPTERM> ...\n \"[\" ...\n \"{\" ...\n <NUMBER> ...\n ]; }{[ekOgLtQNSSCtW0MgoPA6wQ][ddhcpconfs][3]: SearchParseException[[ddhcpconfs][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"00:14:22:47:41:9f\",\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},\"size\":15}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[ddhcpconfs] Failed to parse query [00:14:22:47:41:9f]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse '00:14:22:47:41:9f': Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 5.\nWas expecting one of:\n <EOF> \n <AND> ...\n <OR> ...\n <NOT> ...\n \"+\" ...\n \"-\" ...\n <BAREOPER> ...\n \"(\" ...\n \"*\" ...\n \"^\" ...\n <QUOTED> ...\n <TERM> ...\n <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\n <PREFIXTERM> ...\n <WILDTERM> ...\n <REGEXPTERM> ...\n \"[\" ...\n \"{\" ...\n <NUMBER> ...\n ]; nested: ParseException[Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 5.\nWas expecting one of:\n <EOF> \n <AND> ...\n <OR> ...\n <NOT> ...\n \"+\" ...\n \"-\" ...\n <BAREOPER> ...\n \"(\" ...\n \"*\" ...\n \"^\" ...\n <QUOTED> ...\n <TERM> ...\n <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\n <PREFIXTERM> ...\n <WILDTERM> ...\n <REGEXPTERM> ...\n \"[\" ...\n \"{\" ...\n <NUMBER> ...\n ]; }{[ekOgLtQNSSCtW0MgoPA6wQ][ddhcpconfs][4]: SearchParseException[[ddhcpconfs][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"00:14:22:47:41:9f\",\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},\"size\":15}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[ddhcpconfs] Failed to parse query [00:14:22:47:41:9f]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse '00:14:22:47:41:9f': Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 5.\nWas expecting one of:\n <EOF> \n <AND> ...\n <OR> ...\n <NOT> ...\n \"+\" ...\n \"-\" ...\n <BAREOPER> ...\n \"(\" ...\n \"*\" ...\n \"^\" ...\n <QUOTED> ...\n <TERM> ...\n <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\n <PREFIXTERM> ...\n <WILDTERM> ...\n <REGEXPTERM> ...\n \"[\" ...\n \"{\" ...\n <NUMBER> ...\n ]; nested: ParseException[Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 5.\nWas expecting one of:\n <EOF> \n <AND> ...\n <OR> ...\n <NOT> ...\n \"+\" ...\n \"-\" ...\n <BAREOPER> ...\n \"(\" ...\n \"*\" ...\n \"^\" ...\n <QUOTED> ...\n <TERM> ...\n <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\n <PREFIXTERM> ...\n <WILDTERM> ...\n <REGEXPTERM> ...\n \"[\" ...\n \"{\" ...\n <NUMBER> ...\n ]; }{[ekOgLtQNSSCtW0MgoPA6wQ][ddhcpconfs][0]: SearchParseException[[ddhcpconfs][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"00:14:22:47:41:9f\",\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},\"size\":15}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[ddhcpconfs] Failed to parse query [00:14:22:47:41:9f]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse '00:14:22:47:41:9f': Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 5.\nWas expecting one of:\n <EOF> \n <AND> ...\n <OR> ...\n <NOT> ...\n \"+\" ...\n \"-\" ...\n <BAREOPER> ...\n \"(\" ...\n \"*\" ...\n \"^\" ...\n <QUOTED> ...\n <TERM> ...\n <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\n <PREFIXTERM> ...\n <WILDTERM> ...\n <REGEXPTERM> ...\n \"[\" ...\n \"{\" ...\n <NUMBER> ...\n ]; nested: ParseException[Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 5.\nWas expecting one of:\n <EOF> \n <AND> ...\n <OR> ...\n <NOT> ...\n \"+\" ...\n \"-\" ...\n <BAREOPER> ...\n \"(\" ...\n \"*\" ...\n \"^\" ...\n <QUOTED> ...\n <TERM> ...\n <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\n <PREFIXTERM> ...\n <WILDTERM> ...\n <REGEXPTERM> ...\n \"[\" ...\n \"{\" ...\n <NUMBER> ...\n ]; }{[ekOgLtQNSSCtW0MgoPA6wQ][ddhcpconfs][1]: SearchParseException[[ddhcpconfs][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"00:14:22:47:41:9f\",\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}},\"size\":15}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[ddhcpconfs] Failed to parse query [00:14:22:47:41:9f]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse '00:14:22:47:41:9f': Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 5.\nWas expecting one of:\n <EOF> \n <AND> ...\n <OR> ...\n <NOT> ...\n \"+\" ...\n \"-\" ...\n <BAREOPER> ...\n \"(\" ...\n \"*\" ...\n \"^\" ...\n <QUOTED> ...\n <TERM> ...\n <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\n <PREFIXTERM> ...\n <WILDTERM> ...\n <REGEXPTERM> ...\n \"[\" ...\n \"{\" ...\n <NUMBER> ...\n ]; nested: ParseException[Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 5.\nWas expecting one of:\n <EOF> \n <AND> ...\n <OR> ...\n <NOT> ...\n \"+\" ...\n \"-\" ...\n <BAREOPER> ...\n \"(\" ...\n \"*\" ...\n \"^\" ...\n <QUOTED> ...\n <TERM> ...\n <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\n <PREFIXTERM> ...\n <WILDTERM> ...\n <REGEXPTERM> ...\n \"[\" ...\n \"{\" ...\n <NUMBER> ...\n ]; }]","status":400}
```

Please help....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace all the colon  by '\:' then I replace the first colon if I use attribute search ie : ip:172.30.5.85.

```
class Ddhcpconf < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Tire::Model::Search
    include Tire::Model::Callbacks


    tire.mapping do
        indexes :nomdns, :index_analyser => 'keyword', :search_analyser => 'keyword'
        indexes :ddns, :index_analyser => 'keyword', :search_analyser => 'keyword'
        indexes :comment, :index_analyser => 'keyword', :search_analyser => 'keyword'
        indexes :zonedhcp, :index_analyser => 'keyword', :search_analyser => 'keyword'
        indexes :mac, :index_analyser => 'keyword', :search_analyser => 'keyword'
        indexes :ip, :index_analyser => 'keyword', :search_analyser => 'keyword'
    end

    def self.search(params)
        if params[:query].present?
            if params[:query] =~ /^ip:/ || params[:query] =~ /^mac:/ || params[:query] =~ /^zonedhcp:/ || params[:query] =~ /^comment:/ || params[:query] =~ /^ddns:/ || params[:query] =~ /^nomdns:/
                recherche = params[:query].gsub(/:/, '\:')
                recherche = recherche.sub(/^([^:]+)\\:/, '\1:')
            else
                recherche = '"' + params[:query].gsub(/:/, '\:') + '"'
            end
        end
        tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 15) do |s|
            s.query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND"} if params[:query].present?
            s.sort { by :ip, "asc" } if params[:query].blank? || params[:query].present?
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks @geeky_sh

Answer (score 0):

When you are searching for a specific mac address, you should use **term** query to find the results. It is because, term query does not analyze the query field (your mac address in this case). Here is the elasticsearch query:

```
query: {
  term: {
    mac: '//your mac address..'
  }
}
```

**tire** query:

```
def self.search(params)
  tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 15) do |s|
     s.query { term :mac, params[:query]} if params[:query].present?
  end
end
```

Update:

I checked your problem on my end, and I found the solution. The problem in your case, is you are setting `keyword_analyzer` for your mac address. Instead use, `keyword`. It should work fine.

I would advise you to use [term query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) as it does not analyze the term that you use the search for.

Note that by setting `keyword` analyzer for mac. address. You can search the ES documents only when you enter the whole mac. address.

Comment: I can't find how to code your answer. It is possible to have somme help. Again... Thanks

Comment: i tried this but it doesn't work :         tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 15) do
            query do
                boolean do
        #           must { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
                    must { terms :mac, Array(params[:query]) }
                end
            end
        end
    end

Comment: I have updated the answer, with the tire version of the query. Check it out

Comment: Thanks a lot but it doesn't work. I have no error and no result.

Comment: I am not sure whether your documents are indexed properly or at all. Can you post the output of `Tire.search 'enter your index', query: {'match_all' => {}}`. Does this give you all the documents?

Comment: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/dhcplogs/_search?pretty -d '
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}'
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 10000,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "dhcplogs",
      "_type" : "dhcplog",
      "_id" : "4",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"datelog":"2013-10-29T06:26:51.000Z","ip":"172.20.178.13","mac":"ac:22:0b:c3:62:04"}
    },` ......

Comment: I have it updated the answer. Check it out. I think it should work for you now